# Sorting joined table with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: sorting, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

I set up a test to get more familiar with Symfony2 and KnpPaginatorBundle. I have a table with pets that references the pet animal type (`Dog`, `Cat`, Etc). I can sort by the `id`, `name`, but when I try to sort by animal `type` I get an error message stating:

> There is no such field [animalkind] in the given Query component, aliased by [a]

I have tried various field names, but nothing seems to work.

Entity: `MyPets.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Xyz\TestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MyPet
 */

class MyPet
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return MyPet
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return MyPet
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    /**
     * @var \Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\AnimalKind
     */
    private $AnimalKind;

    /**
     * Set AnimalKind
     *
     * @param \Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\AnimalKind $animalKind
     * @return MyPet
     */
    public function setAnimalKind(\Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\AnimalKind $animalKind)
    {
        $this->AnimalKind = $animalKind;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get AnimalKind
     *
     * @return \Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\AnimalKind 
     */
    public function getAnimalKind()
    {
        return $this->AnimalKind;

    }
}
```

Entity: `AnimalKind.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Xyz\TestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AnimalKind
 */
class AnimalKind {

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return AnimalKind
     */
    public function setType($type) {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $MyPets;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->MyPets = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add MyPets
     *
     * @param \Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\MyPet $myPets
     * @return AnimalKind
     */
    public function addMyPet(\Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\MyPet $myPets) {
        $this->MyPets[] = $myPets;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove MyPets
     *
     * @param \Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\MyPet $myPets
     */
    public function removeMyPet(\Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\MyPet $myPets) {
        $this->MyPets->removeElement($myPets);
    }

    /**
     * Get MyPets
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMyPets() {
        return $this->MyPets;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getType();
    }

}
```

Controller: `MyPetController.php` (`IndexAction`)

```php
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT a FROM XyzTestBundle:MyPet a");

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query,$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 
          1)/*page number*/,15/*limit per page*/);

        return $this->render('XyzTestBundle:MyPet:index.html.twig', array(
         'pagination' => $pagination,

        ));
    }
```

View: `MyPet/index.html.twig` (snipped)

```
<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {# sorting of properties based on query components #}
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Id', 'a.id') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Name', 'a.name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'kind', 'a.animalkind') }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for mypet in pagination %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('xyz_mypet_show', { 'id': mypet.id }) }}">{{ mypet.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ mypet.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ mypet.animalkind }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone give me any insight as to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue is the missing ORM relationship declaration; basically in your DB `YourPet` cannot be associated to an `AnimalKind`.

You can find documentation about [Entity relationships and associations on the Symfony's website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations).

From `YourPet` entity's point of view, you probably want to use a ManyToOne relationship.

The second issue, once you fix the problem above, is that you are not joining the `AnimalKind` entity in your query.

The third issue is that you cannot order a query result by an entity.

First issue potential solution:

```
// In MyPet class
/**
 * @var \Xyz\TestBundle\Entity\AnimalKind
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AnimalKind", inversedBy="MyPets")
 */
private $AnimalKind;

// In AnimalKind class
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyPet", inversedBy="AnimalKind")
 */
private $MyPets;
```

Second issue potential solution:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT a, k
    FROM XyzTestBundle:MyPet a
    JOIN a.animalKind k 
");
```

Third issue potential solution:

```
<th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'kind', 'k.type') }}</th>
```

Comment: Thanks Elnur!  I did not change the Entities, but I added the JOIN and the k.type code as you suggested and it worked. After thinking about it I really needed to sort by animalkind.type.

Answer (score 0):

To display animals with no animalKind you'll have to use a LEFT JOIN in your query

```
$query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT a, k
    FROM XyzTestBundle:MyPet a
    LEFT JOIN a.animalKind k 
");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using query builder and DQL and still looking for answer:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->select('a', 'k')
        ->leftJoin(
            'a.animalKind',
            'k'
        )
    ;
```

Assumption -> you have correctly created relation in your entity.